# "borrowed value does not live long enough" when using `as_slice`

Tags: rust

I keep running into the problem and I don't quite understand why the won't compile this:

```
fn foo(bar: &'static str) -> Foo {
  let caps_off = bar.to_ascii_lower().as_slice();
  ...
}
```

Error: `borrowed value does not live long enough`

I sort of understand the error here but I don't know any other way to achieve this.

I'm try to convert my `str` to lowercase & then convert it back to type `str`. Seems simple.

What am I doing wrong here & how can I fix it?

full code:

```
use std::collections::HashMap;
use std::ascii::StrAsciiExt;

struct Foo;

fn foo(bar: &'static str) -> Foo {
  let caps_off_ = bar.to_ascii_lower();
  let caps_off = caps_off_.as_slice();

  let mut my_foos:HashMap<&'static str, Foo> = HashMap::new();
  my_foos.insert("hi", Foo);
  *my_foos.find(&caps_off).clone().unwrap()
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should post your full code for us to understand the error, but in that code, the compiler can not tell how long the new string lives.
So try with:

```
fn foo(bar: &'static str) -> Foo {
  let caps_off_ = bar.to_ascii_lower();
  let caps_off  = caps_off_.as_slice();
  ...
}
```

so `caps_off_` holds the new `String` object while you use the slice.

EDIT:

Adding to the previous answer, just how Francis explained, you declared that the map's keys are `&'static str`, so `find` won't accept a key that doesn't match that same signature. So you have two choices 1) Declaring the map as `<&str, Foo>` without a static lifetime or 2) Use the `find_equiv` method.

Hope it helped.

Comment: Please see the full code above. This is very confusing. Is there a way that I can manually tell the compiler that "I'm not done using `caps_off` yet"?

Comment: If you put a code I can compile that shows your error, I may help you. It must be something about lifetimes.

Comment: Ok, sure. Please see my edit. The code should compile now

Answer (score 2):

The error is tricky to understand because of information the compiler inferred.

What's the type of `caps_off`? You didn't specify it, so the compiler must infer it from its usage. It's only use once, in this expression

```
*my_foos.find(&caps_off).clone().unwrap()
```

The [`find` method](http://doc.rust-lang.org/std/collections/trait.Map.html#tymethod.find) on the [`Map` trait](http://doc.rust-lang.org/std/collections/trait.Map.html) specifies that the parameter is of type `&K`. You defined your map as a `HashMap<&'static str, Foo>`, therefore `K` is `&'static str`. Consequently, the parameter's concrete type is `&&'static str`. The argument is `&caps_off`, so you are building a reference. The compiler infers that `caps_off` must be of type `&'static str` to match the parameter's type. And here's the problem.

The error is telling you that `caps_off_.as_slice()` cannot be assigned to `caps_off`, because the borrowed slice doesn't live long enough. That's because `bar.to_ascii_lower()` returns a `String`, and that string only lives for the duration of the function call. This means that you can't use `Map.find()` with this value.

Fortunately, there's another method on `HashMap` that solves your problem: [`find_equiv`](http://doc.rust-lang.org/std/collections/struct.HashMap.html#method.find_equiv). By using it, the compiler can infer a different type for `caps_off` that's compatible with the expression you're trying to assign to it (`&'a str`). Just change the last line in `foo` to use it:

```
*my_foos.find_equiv(&caps_off).clone().unwrap()
```

In fact, you don't even need to call `as_slice()`, you can pass the `String` returned from `bar.to_ascii_lower()` directly, and you don't need to define a variable if you only use the lowercase string once:

```
*my_foos.find_equiv(&bar.to_ascii_lower()).clone().unwrap()
```